# What am I missing? Trying to get Regex to work that came from json

Tags: javascript, json, regex

I have this regex all escaped in my json file.

```
"\/^Grocer(?:ies|y)[ \\t]*(\\S+)?\/gmi"
```

I then tried to put that into a new regex

```
  var re = new RegExp("\/^Grocer(?:ies|y)[ \\t]*(\\S+)?\/gmi");
  console.log(re.exec("Groceries"));
```

but it fails. So I thought maybe it is the escaping so I used unescape() which gave me.

```
  var re = new RegExp("/^Grocer(?:ies|y)[ \t]*(\S+)?/gmi");
  console.log(re.exec("Groceries"));
```

Still fails.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are looking for this:

```
var re = new RegExp("^Grocer(?:ies|y)[ \t]*(\S+)?", "gmi");
console.log(re.exec("Groceries"));
```

Output: `["Groceries", ...]`

The `/` at the beginning and end is also escaped (`\/`), and you were including those.  They need to be removed as well.

Try this:

```
var s = "\/^Grocer(?:ies|y)[ \\t]*(\\S+)?\/gmi";
var parts = s.match(/\/(.*)\/(\w*)/);
var re = new RegExp(parts[1], parts[2]);
console.log(re.exec("Groceries"));
```

Comment: The `/` at the beginning and end weren't escaped in the eyes of the regex, but yes, they do need to be removed when using the `new RegExp(...)` form.

Comment: From your post, it seemed that `/^Grocer(?:ies|y)[ \t]*(\S+)?/gmi` was the string value (after the escaped characters were processed).  You needed to extract the ^Grocer(?:ies|y)[ \t]*(\S+)?` part, and the flags from between `/`.

Comment: I'm not OP, but OP he could probably use a regex to extract the regex :D

Answer (score 0):

Regex in JS doesn't normally need quotes around the string so try

```
 var re = new RegExp(/^Grocer(?:ies|y)[ \t]*(\S+)?/gmi);
 console.log(re.exec("Groceries"));
```

More information can be found here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp

If you are looping through a JSON object then you might need to do something like this for each iteration of your loop

```
// while you are in the loop
var thisRegex = unescape( thisLoopItem ); // fill this in with the current item

// locate the final slash
var finalSlash = thisRegex.lastIndexOf('/');

// use substr to return the string before and after the slash to
// populate both parts of the RegExp function
var re = new RegExp( thisRegex.substr( 0, finalSlash ), thisRegex.substr( finalSlash + 1 ) );
console.log(re.exec("Groceries"));
```

That may need a bit of tweaking but something along those lines will work.

Comment: Yea, I did try that(and it works) but the thing is in my json I got it like      "names": ["\/^Grocer(?:ies|y)[ \\t]*(\\S+)?\/gmi"]. So it is wrapped as a string. So not sure what to do in that case.

Comment: You can replace the surrounding ```/``` with single quotes I believe.

Comment: I am not sure what you mean, I don't think single quotes can be used in an array in json.

Comment: Have updated my answer to hopefully point you in the right direction

Answer (score 0):

The RegExp constructor signature is as follows

```
var re = new RegExp(pattern[, flags])
```

E.g: `new RegExp('abc', 'i');`

So, the following code would work for you.

```
var regTxt ="\/^Grocer(?:ies|y)[ \\t]*(\\S+)?\/gmi" // from Json
var regexParts = regTxt.match(/\/(.*)\/(\w*)/)
var re = new RegExp(regexParts[1], regexParts[2]);
console.log(re.exec("Groceries"));
```

Output : `["Groceries", ..]`